# Decompositon of the Space of Maass Forms

Tags: modular-forms, automorphic-forms

In the space of Maass forms (weight 0, level 1 for simplicity) there are the cusp forms and also the (real analytic) Eisenstein series. None others come to mind, but is the space of Maass forms simply the direct sum of cusps forms and Eisenstein series?

This is true for modular forms, but for Maass forms the constant coefficient has two complex parameters, and so it seems like in general you can't cancel out the constant term of a general Maass form with just the Eisenstein series.

Comment: Why should $E(2z,s)$ be a Maass form though? At least it won't be of the same level in general. Regarding the idea to consider $E(z,s)$ and $E(z,1-s)$, the problem is that the constant terms are proportional, because of the functional equation for $E(z,s)$.

Comment: Right $f(z)+a E(z,s)+b E(2z,s)$ is of level 2, it [vanishes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maass_wave_form#Theorem:_E_is_a_Maass_form) at the $i\infty$ cusp but not at $0$. What about $f(z)+a E(z,s)+b E(2z,s)+b E(z/2,s)$ again of level 2

Comment: Yeah. Well, it's an interesting point to consider forms of different levels. I think there should be a resolution to the case of fixed level though. For example, if we fix the level as 1 and consider only Maass forms of a certain eigenvalue (for the Laplacian), the codimension of the cups forms in the space of Maass forms is at most 2. It is at least 1 because we have the Eisenstein series associated to the given eigenvalue. So is this dimension 1 or 2? I'm surprised nothing is written about this anywhere.

Comment: In [Garrett](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/) there is that $L^2(SL_2(Z)\setminus H)$ has a basis of cusp forms, and from the Mellin transform  $F(s) =\int_0^\infty f(iy) y^{-s-1}dy$ you have that $f(z)-\int_{(r)} F(s) E(z,s)ds$  vanishes on $\Re(z)=0$, thus if your $f$ satisfies $f(z)-f(iy) = O(e^{-y})$ then $f(z)-c E(s,z)$ should be a cusp form

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your idea. Where does the Eisenstein series come into the Mellin transform? Also, what is $c$ and what is the $s$ chosen in the final line?

Comment: The answer to your question is (essentially) yes, once you also include the constant function and you take into account that you need a direct *integral* of Eisenstein series. See Theorem 15.5 of Iwaniec-Kowalski.

Comment: I think what you are describing is Selberg's spectral decomposition. This deals only with $L^2$ Maass forms though, which are the cusp forms. Eisenstein series are not cusp forms even though they are used to describe the spectral decomposition as you mention. So my question is about the non-cusp Maass forms, there are the Eisenstein series but is there anything else?